# MySQL UPDATE query with exceptions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables: `chapter` and `updates`

I have an UPDATE query to set member ids from the `updates` table into the `chapter` table. The problem I am trying to find a syntax solution to is that I need to use one query, but have it NOT update (skip) the value if the update value is `'0'`. When an update is filed (to await UPDATE processing), not all ids are changed, and those that are not are saved into my `updates` table as `'0'` while valid changes are a seven digit integer. The problem arises when an UPDATE is applied, any existing ids are overwritten with the `'0'` when that field should actually have its existing value retained. A sample of my current query is:

```
UPDATE chapter
SET chapter.election_date = updates.election_date,
 chapter.president = updates.president_id,
 chapter.vice_president = updates.vice_president_id,
 chapter.secretary = updates.secretary_id,
WHERE
    updates.chapter_id = chapter.id
AND updates.installation_date < CURRENT_DATE ()
```

Based off of this example, I am trying to find a way to have `chapter.president` NOT be updated if `updates.president_id = '0'`

If this is doable, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: How are the `updates` and `chapter` table related? Is there anything to JOIN them on

Comment: The tables are joined by chapter.id = updates.chapter_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this condition to the `join` clause:

```
UPDATE chapter
JOIN   updates ON updates.chapter_id = chapter.id AND 
                  updates.president_id != '0'
SET    chapter.election_date = updates.election_date,
       chapter.president = updates.president_id,
       chapter.vice_president = updates.vice_president_id,
       chapter.secretary = updates.secretary_id,
WHERE  updates.installation_date < CURRENT_DATE ()
```

Comment: What is the best way to extend this to include checking if other id's are not '0' as well. I used the chapter.president field as an example, but need to check about a dozen other fields as well. To relate that, in my example, this would be the equivalent of not updating any of the fields including chapter.president, chapter.vice_president, chapter.secretary if  updates.president_id !='0', and updates.vice_president_id !='0', updates.secretary_id !='0' as well.

Comment: @MarkHelmstetter the main idea of having it in the join condition still stands. You could use the `in` operator to write it elegantly though: `'0' not in (updates.president_id, updates.vice_president_id, updates.secretary_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

The below query will not update the chapter.president, if updates.president_id=0, but will update all other fields.

```
UPDATE chapter, updates
SET chapter.election_date = updates.election_date,
 chapter.president = if(updates.president_id<>0,updates.president_id,chapter.president)
 chapter.vice_president = updates.vice_president_id,
 chapter.secretary = updates.secretary_id,
WHERE
    updates.chapter_id = chapter.id
AND updates.installation_date < CURRENT_DATE()
```